# How to connect an activity LED to a RocketRAID card?

Tags: led, computers

So this is more computer-based, but definitely electrical so I'm hoping I can find some help, so here goes...

I have a home server (WSE2016) which utilizes a RAID for its primary storage. I had an Intel RAID card which recently failed (RT3WB080, it was very old), and I have replaced it with a Highpoint RocketRAID 2720A RAID card (RR2720A) and restored my data from backup onto the new volume and it all runs great - performance is far better than I expected from a low-priced card.

Here's my problem... the standard HDD activity LED on the case has two leads, a "+" and a "-". The Intel RAID card had a 2-pin connection labeled "+" and "-", easy. The RR2720A has a block of pins, one for each HDD channel (it's fine because if one HDD is working, they all are), but only a single pin the LED is supposed to connect to, and I don't understand how it's supposed to complete the connection.

The pin is labeled as: Normal 3.3V High, Activity 0V Low, which leads me to believe it grounds the connection to signal activity. That would make me believe I should connect the - end of the LED to the activity pin, and + should be connected to a 3.3V source somewhere? (If I remember my electrics correctly, 3.3V on both leads would make LED not lit, but if one side drops from 3.3V to 0V then it will illuminate?

The instructions also say a current limiting resistor is required, but the wiring diagram shows what I think is a diode? And would that be the + or the - on the LED? And where to I connect the other lead? Below are links to both the User Guide and the LED connection guide provided by Highpoint, who is as clueless as I am on the matter.

I've attempted to attach images from the User Guide and LED Guide below.

[image: RR2720A Layout]
[image: RR2720A Connections]
[image: RR2720A LED Connections Guide]

Comment: You will probably find an GND pin closeby. Try around or test with a multimeter when unplugged.

Comment: If I connected the 2nd pin to ground, wouldn't that make the LED lit all the time since the card PIN is normally high 3.3V?

Comment: A site rule that may cause your question to be closed: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* <-- if you can provide circuit details it may stay open.

Comment: Depends if the output LED driver is high or low side (open drain/collector). Connect a cable to it and probe with your multimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect it with the + lead of the LED on 3.3v, and the negative lead on the indicator pin. The diode you mention in the schematic on the bottom is the LED itself. The image is quite blurry, but you can see the box on the left of the diode is labeled "A1," which is the pin shown in the diagram above to be the LED pin. You can likely forgo the current limiting resistor as an LED will not pull enough current at 3.3v to cause damage.

Comment: Thank you! I spliced off the 3.3V line from the PSU to the LED + and connected the - to the A1 pin. Seems to work!